# String reversal performance

Tags: java, string, algorithm, reverse

After being intrigued by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439141/what-is-the-most-efficient-algorithm-for-reversing-a-string-in-java) I tried to copy the algorithm that the user Simon Nickerson suggested as well as the algorithm that the top answer provided from docjar: [docjar algorithm](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java.html#1351).

I tested both out (which hopefully I did not make any performance breaking changes by removing the surrogate pair - dealing parts) and I found docjar algorithm to be almost four times faster than Simon's algorithm. Could anyone point out the significant difference between these two algorithms that has this impact on speed because I don't seem to be able to figure it out myself.
Cheers!
(Update) I did 100 trials using System.nanoTime() and I found docjar to average around 4380 nano seconds and the slower algorithm around 13684 nano seconds. 
My modified docjar algorithm (4 times faster):

```
public static String fastReverse(String original)
{
    char[] comps = original.toCharArray();

    int n = comps.length - 1;

    for(int j = (n - 1) >> 1 ; j >= 0; --j)
    {           
        char temp = comps[j];
        char temp2 = comps[n - j];
        comps[j] = temp2;
        comps[n - j] = temp;
    }

    return new String(comps);
}
```

Simon's modified Algorithm(slower):

```
public static String reverse(String original)
{
    char[] comps = original.toCharArray();

    int n = comps.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
    {
        char temp = comps[i];
        comps[i] = comps[n - i - 1];
        comps[n - i - 1] = temp;
    }

    return new String(comps);
}
```

Comment: Before we go any deeper, how exactly are you benchmarking those methods?

Comment: Of course feel free to suggest any more advanced benchmarking methods as I'm an amateur on the subject

Comment: @AlexKoukoulas: I suggest you read through this post first. If your results are still the same then it's worth taking a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Apart from benchmarking questions,

An initial reading shows that there is significantly more arithmetic occurring in Simon's algorithm.

In each loop the modified DocJar has:

- 1 boolean Expression
- 3 subtraction operations.
- 2 primitive Declarations
- 4 array lookups
- 4 assignments

Simon's algorithm has:

- List item
- 1 Boolean expression
- 1 Division
- 1 Addition
- 1 Primitive Declaration
- 4 subtraction operations
- 4 array lookups
- 3 Assignments.

If you wanted to micro-optimize your version even further you could put the 2 char declarations outside of your for loop. (even though any decent compiler would do this for you, its not guaranteed )